# ARMv7 & Cortex-M3 - NVIC registers

Tags: cortex-m, armv7

I am little bit confused with respect the registers which are present in the NVIC(Nested Vectored Interrupt Controller) module is concerned.

Cortex-M3 implements ARMv7M architecture profile.

When I look into the arm architecture v7m reference manual(DDI0403D) for NVIC I see some registers for example master control register @0xE000E000 (reserved) , co-processor register(CPACR) present  @0xE000ED88 (System Control address space).

However, the technical reference manual for cortex M3 on the arm site [link](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/BHCFCFDB.html) shows no registers present at the above address.

Does it mean that Cortex-M3 processor core doesn't have those registers?
It looks like its enough if a processor core conforms only to the instructions present in the architecture.

But why does Cortex-M3 doesn't have those registers when it says it implements ARMv7M?
I might have wrongly understood the above things.
Any light on this topic is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share the technical reference manual of Cortex M3 and ARMv7M and highlight the related sections ?

Comment: @KarthikBalaguru I have added the link to Coretx-M3. For the Armv7M you will have to download it from the arm site(it isn't accessible online I guess).

Comment: I find that NVIC memory map information in the link seems to be superseded. Please check.